# Join on hardcoded values on table built inline

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server '16.

I've built the following inline table:

```
   SELECT * FROM 
   (VALUES('ALPL', 'cat1'),
     ('APLM', 'cat1'),
     ('BATA', 'cat2'),
     ('BPL', 'cat3'),
     ('LOF', 'cat4'),
     ('FLSH', 'cat5'),
     ('BPL', 'cat5'),
     ('FEPL', 'cat5'),
     ('MPL', 'cat5'),)
   AS categories(groupcd, Category)
```

and need to join categories to the results from groupcd from this existing query:

```
   SELECT 
   Storeno
  ,groupcd
  ,Date
  ,Sum([TEXTEND]) as Sales
   FROM [DB ].[dbo].[DTL] DTL 
   join
   ICDB..HDR HDR on HDR.Orderno = DTL.OrderNo
   where groupcd in('ACPL', 'ADV',  'ALPL', 'APLM', 'BATA', 'BOSU', 'BOT',  'BPL',  'FARM', 'FEPL', 'FLSH', 'LOF',  'MAST', 'MBT',  'MPL',  'MSPL', 'OTT',  'SNT',  'SPE',  'SSL',  'TIRL', 'TIRM', 'TPMS')
   and  Date>= convert(datetime,'01/01/2018') 
   group by Storeno, Date, groupcd
```

I don't know how to join to the table since it doesn't exist in a DB.

I need 'Category' field from 1st table in the results from 2nd table.

Thank you,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a CTE:

```
WITH categories(groupcd, Category) as (
      SELECT * 
      FROM (VALUES('ALPL', 'cat1'),
     ('APLM', 'cat1'),
     ('BATA', 'cat2'),
     ('BPL', 'cat3'),
     ('LOF', 'cat4'),
     ('FLSH', 'cat5'),
     ('BPL', 'cat5'),
     ('FEPL', 'cat5'),
     ('MPL', 'cat5')
       ) AS categories(groupcd, Category)
    )
SELECT . . 
FROM categories c . . .
```